# How do you use multidimensional arrays as methods parameter in c++?

Tags: c++

I come from java where i would put multidimensional array as methods parameter like so:

```
void someMethod(int MultiDimensionalArray[][][]){}
```

how would i do this in c++?

Comment: You cannot.  The size of the first dimension is optional, but the others are needed by the compiler to determine the "shape" of the array in memory.  Such is the cost for speed.  Check into the template class [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which may be what you need.

Comment: @JHBonarius No they haven't. Even if the declaration was well-formed (i.e. specified inner dimensions), there would only be one (implicit) star.

Comment: @JHBonarius That's what I'm saying. If it wasn't a function parameter, then there would be no layers of indirection because of the outer array being adjusted to a pointer. As a function parameter, it has a single layer of indirection. (If it was well-formed in the first place, which would require specifying the inner dimensions).

Comment: `int[][][]` isn't a C++ type, nor can it form part of a function declaration

Comment: @JHBonarius That's right. There isn't any more indirection there than there is in `int i; i = 42;`.

Comment: BTW, Java doesn't really have multidimensional arrays. In Java, `int[][]` is an array of arrays (i.e. not contiguous). The closest to in in C++ would be a vector of vectors.

Comment: @rustyx A multidimensional array is an array of arrays. What Java has is arrays of references to arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function argument cannot be an array in C++. You can write a function declaration with an array parameter, but it is actually adjusted to be a pointer to element of such array. For example, these declare the same function, which accepts pointer to an integer:

```
void foo(int arr[]);
void foo(int* arr);
```

The element of a multi dimensional array is an array of smaller rank. For example a 3D array is a actually a 1D array with 2D arrays as elements. So, if you declare a function that accepts a 3D array, then the parameter is adjusted to be a pointer to a 2D array.

A pointer parameter to an array can only point to an array of specific size. So, this would be possible:

```
void foo(int arr[][42][7]);
void foo(int* arr[42][7]);
```

These declare a function that accepts a pointer to a 2D array of size 42 rows and 7 columns.

As such, there is no way to write a function that accepts a multi-dimensional array with unspecified inner dimensions. However, C++ has function templates. You can write a template that accepts an parameter of any type that is deduced from the argument:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& t);
```

You can call such template with a multi-dimensional argument, the parameter type will be deduced accordingly, and a function accepting such argument will be created. Templates such as this can accept any array dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent to a Java array would be `std::vector`

```
void someMethod(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> MultiDimensionalArray){}
```

If you really wanted to use raw arrays, you will have to provide the dimensions.

```
void someMethod(int MultiDimensionalArray[][2][3]){}
```

If you want to handle any size, you will need a template. As Java uses implicit references, this takes a refence to a 3d array of int.

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t O, std::size_t P>
void someMethod(int (&MultiDimensionalArray)[N][O][P]){}
```

Comment: I was wrong with my comments to the OP, but I'm pretty sure `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` does have three layers of indirection. And passing by value could be an expensive copy operation